# Making diagram by vertices' coordinates

Tags: excel, graph, diagram, vertices

I have some vertices' coordinates to build the graph which should look like this:
[image]

The problem is I don't know how to point those coordinates for Excel. They are something like this:

```
X   Y
-----------
5   16
5   13
5   10
5   7,5
5   3,5

X   Y
-----------
12,5    15
12,5    8
```

I know that it may be done easily in OpenGL for example but now it is necessary to implement it in MS Excel. Is it possible by using its diagram tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by diagram tool but a very basic example using an inserted Scatter with Straight Lines and Markers chart:

[image: SO24446112 example]